# ApiPlatform - FK error on an entity related to an other entity

Tags: php, symfony, orm, api-platform.com

I'm using ApiPlatform 3.1.13 and I have an issue I can't fix.

I have a class ShoppingList which have a field items represented by class ItemShoppingList.
You will find the code here :

```
namespace App\Entity\ShoppingList;

use ApiPlatform\Api\QueryParameterValidator\Validator\Length;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\ShoppingList\ShoppingListRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Valid;

#[ApiResource(
    paginationEnabled: false,
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['serialize']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['serialize']],
)]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ShoppingListRepository::class)]
class ShoppingList
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups('serialize')]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 50)]
    #[Groups('serialize')]
    #[Length(min: 1, max: 50)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'shoppingList', targetEntity: ItemShoppingList::class, orphanRemoval: true, cascade: ["persist", "remove"])]
    #[Groups('serialize')]
    #[Valid()]
    #[ORM\OrderBy(["position" => "ASC"])]
    private Collection $items;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->items = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): static
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeItem(ItemShoppingList $item): static
    {
        if ($this->items->removeElement($item)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($item->getShoppingList() === $this) {
                $item->setShoppingList(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, ItemShoppingList>
     */
    public function getItems(): Collection
    {
        return $this->items;
    }

    public function addItem(ItemShoppingList $item): static
    {
        if (!$this->items->contains($item)) {
            $this->items->add($item);
            $item->setShoppingList($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}

<?php

namespace App\Entity\ShoppingList;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Link;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;
use App\Repository\ShoppingList\ItemShoppingListRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;

#[ApiResource(
    paginationEnabled: false,
    uriTemplate: '/shopping_lists/{id}/item_shopping_lists',
    uriVariables: [
        'id' => new Link(fromClass: ShoppingList::class, toProperty: 'shoppingList'),
    ],
    operations: [ new GetCollection() ]
)]
#[ApiResource(
    paginationEnabled: false,
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['serialize']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['serialize']],
)]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ItemShoppingListRepository::class)]
class ItemShoppingList
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups('serialize')]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 50)]
    #[Groups('serialize')]
    #[Length(min: 1, max: 50)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups('serialize')]
    private ?bool $isChecked = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups('serialize')]
    private ?int $position = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'items')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?ShoppingList $shoppingList = null;
 
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): static
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsChecked(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->isChecked;
    }

    public function setIsChecked(bool $isChecked): static
    {
        $this->isChecked = $isChecked;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPosition(): ?int
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function setPosition(int $position): static
    {
        $this->position = $position;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getShoppingList(): ?ShoppingList
    {
        return $this->shoppingList;
    }

    public function setShoppingList(?ShoppingList $shoppingList): static
    {
        $this->shoppingList = $shoppingList;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

When I try to POST an ItemShoppingList to my api, I encountered the error :
`"hydra:description": "An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'shopping_list_id' cannot be null"`

Sure, cause I can't set my shopping_list_id.
I try to with a shoppingListId field related to shopping_list_id but I have the same result.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Did you try to set it this way: $my_shopping_item->setShoppingList($existing_shopping_list); You might be using IDs instead of objects. It would be helpful if you would show us how you are trying to create a new ItemShoppingList.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the serialization groups attribute to `$shoppingList` in `ItemShoppingList`

```
#[Groups('serialize')]
#[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'items')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
private ?ShoppingList $shoppingList = null;
```

I would also recommend not having the same normalization group name for both entities in `#[ApiResource]`